# C# Entity Framework Core: how do I get the relationship of the bill to the vendor without including the vendor's list of bills?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, include, database-relations

I am trying to exclude a relationship from a database query using linq in Entity Framework Core.

I have a database where I have a table of Bills and a table of Vendors.

- Each `Bill` has 1 `Vendor`
- Each `Vendor` has many `Bills`

I want to exclude the `List<Bill>` from the `Vendor` while maintaining the `Vendor` information for the `Bill` I am querying. So I can gather `Vendor` information from that specific `Bill`.
I currently have the relation as below.

```
foundBills = db_context.Bills.Include(v => v.Vendor).Where(searchLambda).ToList();
```

Is there a `.Exclude` or `.Intersect` or something that I am missing to exclude the circular relationship? It is using way too much memory.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: What is searchLambda in this context.

Comment: lets say 
b => b.InvoiceNumber.Contains(invoiceNumber)
It's really any search of a Bill property

Comment: Use following to flatten list to make it easier to process : var bills = db_context.Vendor.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.Bills)).ToList();

Comment: The x => x.Select inside the 'SelectMany' won't work.

Comment: Also in EF core, relationship fixup happens and can't be stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configured your `Bill` and `Vendor` Model classes correctly for "One to Many" relationship, they should look like this:

```cs
public class Vendor
{
    // ... other properties

    public Bill Bill { get; set; }
}

public class Bill
{
    // ... other properties

    public ICollection<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
}
```

With this logic, there shouldn't be any circular dependency, because this is how it works.

Later you can use `Include` or not, but if you want to not have a `Bill` information in your `Vendor` for the final output then create separate models for `Vendor` and `Bill`:

```cs
public class BillOutput
{
    public List<VendorOutput> Vendors { get; set; }
}


public class VendorOutput
{
    // ... other properties
}
```

and later:

```cs
var finalOutput = db_context.Bills.Include(v => v.Vendor).Where(searchLambda).
                      Select(items => new BillOutput
                      {
                          Vendors = items.Select(item => new VendorOutput
                          {
                              // here you don't have the Bill Information
                          }
                      } )
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: *there shouldn't be any circular dependency* -- Well, it *is* a circular dependency and EF will populate both properties as much as possible even if only one is included. But you're right in recommending projection to a custom class. One remark: `Include` isn't necessary in the last statement, it will be ignore because of the projection.